# Issues wrapping border round divs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am having issues applying a border and a border background to a section of my page. I was wondering how I could do this, I've tried make two rows on the same line and apply a border to each but so far nothing I've tried has worked.

To simplify it: My page looks like this https://gyazo.com/ec14ae14dbb369c29759e48dff21cd52

When I need it to look like this https://gyazo.com/d18863ab12fde6cbe458406c6e0fc69a

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="map-holder-image">
                <img src="img/map-holder.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="form" id="border">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="first-name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="email-address" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-address">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="last-name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="confirm-email-address" class="control-label">Confirm Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirm-email-address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4" id="date-picker">
            <label for="dates" class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <select class="date-dropdown" id="day-dropdown-form">
        <script>
            var daylist = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
                daylist += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
            }

            document.getElementById("day-dropdown-form").innerHTML = daylist;
        </script>
        </select>
        <select id="month-dropdown-form">
        <script>
            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            var monthlist = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
                monthlist += "<option>" + months[i] + "</option>";
            }

            document.getElementById("month-dropdown-form").innerHTML = monthlist;
        </script>
        </select>
        <select class="date-dropdown" id="year-dropdown-form">
        <script>
            var yearlist = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 2016; i >= 1900; i--) {
                yearlist += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
            }

            document.getElementById("year-dropdown-form").innerHTML = yearlist;
        </script>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="submit-button-col">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="submit-button" type="button">
                <h3>Submit</h3>
            </button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/*-- Bootstrap overrides instead of editing source LESS files --*/

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    p, div {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    /*-- Custom Styling --*/

    #logo {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #searchbox {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #search-input {
      border: solid 1px gray;
      border-radius: 8px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    #search-input input {
      border: 0;
      box-shadow: none;
      background: none;
    }

    #search-button {
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #search-button button {
      background: none;
      border: none;
    }

    #login-name {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #login-name p {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 50px;
        float: right;
    }

    #settings-icon {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-inner {
      padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar .nav {
      margin: 0;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar .nav li {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 11.1%;
      float: none;
      text-align: center;
      left: 4px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .navbar .nav li a {
      border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

    #active-link {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .navbar .nav li:first-child a {
      border-left: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    .navbar .nav li:last-child a {
      border-right: 0;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    }

    #detail-request {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    #banner-top-col {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #banner-bottom-col {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #banner-top {
      margin: auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
    }

    .banner-information {
      position: absolute;
      border: 5px solid #ff6600;
      background-color: #ebebeb;
      width: 400px;
      height: 180px;
      border-radius: 7px;
      top: 12%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5px;
      left: 5%;
    }

    .banner-information h4 {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .banner-information h1 {
      font-size: 60px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      text-align: left;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #map-holder-image {
      border: 2px solid #ff6600;
      border-radius: 7px;
      width: auto;
      padding: 1px;
    }
    #email-address, #confirm-email-address, #first-name, #last-name {
      width: 85%;
    }


    #contact-form-box {
      border: 1px solid #ff6600;
      width: auto;
      background-color: #ebebeb;
      border-radius: 7px;
    }

    .support-box {
      border: 2px solid #ff6600;
      background-color: #ebebeb;
      border-radius: 7px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 359px;
      margin-right: 18.5px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      right: 10px;
      height: 230px;
    }

    .support-box h3 {
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
    }

     #support {
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 0px solid #ffad41;
      -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
      -moz-border-radius: 16px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      font-size: 38px;
      font-family: arial;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #ffc579;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffc579), to(#fb9d23));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffc579, #fb9d23);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffc579, #fb9d23);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffc579, #fb9d23);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffc579, #fb9d23);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffc579, #fb9d23);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#ffc579, endColorstr=#fb9d23);
      text-align: center;
      height: 80px;
      width: 180px;
    }

    #support:hover {
      border: 0px solid #ff9913;
      background-color: #ffaf46;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffaf46), to(#e78404));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffaf46, #e78404);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffaf46, #e78404);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#ffaf46, endColorstr=#e78404);
    }

    #support-image {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #support h3 {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      padding-right: 15px;
      font-weight: 800;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .date-dropdown {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      background: url("../img/input-triangle.png") no-repeat white;
      background-position: 50px center;
      width: 80px;
      height: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-size: 28px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-right: 22px;
    }

    #date-picker {
      height: 100px;
    }

    #month-dropdown-form {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      background: url("../img/input-triangle.png") no-repeat white;
      background-position: 65px center;
      width: 95px;
      height: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-size: 28px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-right: 22px;
    }

    #submit-button-col {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100px;
    }

    #submit-button {
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 25px;
      border: 0px solid #46ec02;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      font-family: arial;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #46ec02;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#46ec02), to(#28c307));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #46ec02, #28c307);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #46ec02, #28c307);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #46ec02, #28c307);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #46ec02, #28c307);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #46ec02, #28c307);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#46ec02, endColorstr=#28c307);
      text-align: center;
      height: 65px;
      width: 200px;
      margin-right: 45px;
    }

    #submit-button h3 {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-weight: 800;
    }

    #banner-bottom {
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }

    #footer {
      background-color: #363636;
      height: 250px;
    }

    #footer p {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 130px;
    }

    #footer-line {
      border: 1px solid white;
      width: 95%;
    }
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you shorten your code to just the important parts? I can take a look at this then.

Comment: The I notice is your `.image-suppresser` has a fixed with, this is the parent to the image, the image is set to be max-width 100%, so you need to sort out `.image-suppresser`. I dont see any indication of a border in your desired example.

Comment: Ye I've shortened it.